# Lighthouse GraphQL - how to pass array as variable?

Tags: graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm working to build a simple Facebook clone to build up my knowledge of GraphQL. I'm using [lighthouse-php](https://lighthouse-php.com) on top of Laravel to serve my data. Essentially, a user has many friends, and I know this works because in the tinker console I can return the correct data with something like `$user->friends()->get()`. I'm struggling with figuring out how to pass an array of data.

On my frontend, I've got a Vuetify combobox (basically a select dropdown) that builds an array of emails, and this is what I'm trying to pass over to my backend mutation.

How do I structure the type and mutation so that it accepts an array of emails?

**user.graphql:**

```graphql
extend type Mutation @guard(with: ["api"]) {
    addFriends(input: [AddFriendsInput]! @spread): [User]! @field(resolver: "UserMutator@addFriends")
}

type User {
    id: ID!
    email: String!
    password: String!
    first_name: String
    last_name: String
    created_at: DateTime!
    updated_at: DateTime!

    friends: [User]! @belongsToMany(relation: "friends")
}

input AddFriendsInput {
    email: String!
}
```

**addFriend.gql:**

```gql
mutation AddFriends($friends: [AddFriendsInput]!) {
  addFriends(input: { email:[$friends] }){
    id
    email
  }
}
```

Comment: just `mutation AddFriends($friends: [AddFriendsInput]!) {
  addFriends(input: $friends){` ...  define variable type (matching BE signature) and use it as a whole object

Comment: This seems closer! I am getting an error in my GraphQL Playground console: `Uncaught Error: Introspection must provide input type for arguments, but received: [User]!`, and when I run the mutation anyways I get the error `"Variable \"$friends\" got invalid value [{\"email\":\"test@gmail.com\"}]; Field value[0].friends of required type [User]! was not provided."`

Comment: this was about querying/graphql part ... IDK lighthouse - bad args definitions/directives (as passed value matches/is valid for this input type) ?.... return type mixed into the problem (mutation resolver doesn't retunr user array)

Comment: I mean I think it's still related to the graphql definitions, no? At this point it's not even hitting the resolver yet.

Comment: I mean @spread doesn't make sense as only one arg and array type ... you can unify arg/vars naming: `mutation AddFriends($input: [AddFriendsInput]!) {   addFriends(input: $input){` ... and return only some boolean 'success' to separate problems ... explore graphiql/playground docs, check input type, test mutation using query variables before coding FE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok finally got it figured out.

Modified the input to this:

```
input AddFriendsInput {
  email: String!
  # friends: [User]
}
```

and changed my Mutation to this:

```
mutation AddFriends($friends: [AddFriendsInput]!) {
  addFriends(input: $friends) {
    id
    email
  }
}
```

This allows me to pass an array of emails to my resolver now.

Comment: You're right haha, I've been messing around with so many small changes, I didn't realize that's how it originally was when I posted the question. Thanks for your help!